# Python request gets lost on DJango app deployed on IIS

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, tweepy

I have deployed DJango app on IIS. It fetches tweets using tweepy. While i fetch historic tweets in between request gets lost and nothing gets logged and no exception is raised. I have attached code snippet.

**Note:** When i run the same code in debug mode, everything works charm.

This code gets status of each tweet by id.

```
def get_tweet(id, api=None):
    status = []
    try:

        logger.info('retrieve_tweet.get_tweet() invoked.')

        if api is None:
            logger.info('get_tweet api none found.')
            CONSUMER_KEY = config.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY
            CONSUMER_SECRET = config.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET
            ACCESS_TOKEN = config.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN
            ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = config.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET

            auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
            auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

            api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True, retry_count=2,
                            retry_delay=5,
                            retry_errors=[401], timeout=300000)

        status = api.get_status(id, tweet_mode='extended')
        logger.info('retrieve_tweet.get_tweet() end.')
        return status
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error('Exception in retrieve_tweet.get_tweet(): %s', ex)
        return None
```

Below code gets the parent tweet from the fetched conversation:

```
child_status = get_tweet(id=id, api=api)
logger.info('child_status: %s', child_status)

if child_status:
    status.append(child_status._json)
    in_reply_to_status_id = child_status.in_reply_to_status_id

    while in_reply_to_status_id is not None:
        parent_status = get_tweet(id=child_status.in_reply_to_status_id, api=api)
        logger.info('parent status inside while: %s', parent_status)
        if parent_status:
            status.append(parent_status._json)
            in_reply_to_status_id = parent_status.in_reply_to_status_id
            if in_reply_to_status_id is None:
                logger.info('All the parent tweets are found.')
            else:
                child_status = parent_status
        else:
            in_reply_to_status_id = None

if len(status) > 1:
    status = sorted(status, key=lambda x: x['id'])
else:
    logger.info('no parent tweets found.')
    status = None

logger.info('retrieve_tweet.get_parent_tweet() end.')
```

Below are the logs from log file

```
[24/Jul/2018 01:05:01] | INFO | [dashboard.analysis.retreive_tweet:68] : retrieve_tweet.get_parent_tweet() invoked.
[24/Jul/2018 01:05:01] | INFO | [dashboard.analysis.retreive_tweet:69] : parent tweet id: 1021160191147094017
[24/Jul/2018 01:05:01] | INFO | [dashboard.analysis.retreive_tweet:40] : retrieve_tweet.get_tweet() invoked.
[24/Jul/2018 01:05:01] | INFO | [dashboard.analysis.retreive_tweet:57] : retrieve_tweet.get_tweet() end.
[24/Jul/2018 01:05:01] | INFO | [dashboard.analysis.retreive_tweet:106] : no parent tweets found.
[24/Jul/2018 01:05:01] | INFO | [dashboard.analysis.retreive_tweet:109] : retrieve_tweet.get_parent_tweet() end.
[24/Jul/2018 01:05:01] | INFO | [dashboard.analysis.retreive_tweet:68] : retrieve_tweet.get_parent_tweet() invoked.
[24/Jul/2018 01:05:01] | INFO | [dashboard.analysis.retreive_tweet:69] : parent tweet id: 1021158630886977538
[24/Jul/2018 01:05:01] | INFO | [dashboard.analysis.retreive_tweet:40] : retrieve_tweet.get_tweet() invoked.
```

AS after the get_tweet() invoked, there are no logs and throws exception of 500.

Comment: What do you mean, "in between requests"? How are you running this code?

Comment: I make a api call which call this func and i retreive tweets and iterate over all tweets till i find in_reply_to_status_id is none. Between when it iterates after some iteration it terminates without logging any exceptions. But the very same code when i run in debug mode, everything works as expected. @DanielRoseman